# How to return back the object using async task?

Tags: android, multithreading

I am trying to return back the list of tweets after the parsing from async task ....
But I am not getting the arraylist back from the task . 
Can anyone suggest a solution?

```
public class Main extends ListActivity {
    String MY_APP_TAG = "com.list";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ArrayList listItems = new ArrayList();
        new myAsyncTask().execute(listItems);

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.tweet, R.id.tweet,listItems));
        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // When clicked, show a Toaster
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<Object>, Void, Void>
    {
        ArrayList<Object> listItems;
        ProgressDialog dialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Main.this, "", "Loading....");
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(ArrayList<Object>... params) {

            String host = "api.twitter.com";
            String twitterURL = "http://"+host+"/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=i1990jain&amp;count;=10";
            try {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                BasicHttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
                HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost(host, 80, "http");
                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(twitterURL);
                httpget.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(targetHost, httpget, localContext);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                Object content = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                Log.d(MY_APP_TAG, "OK: " + content.toString());

                JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(content.toString());

                for(int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                    listItems.add(jo.getString("text"));
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Either let two threads running asynchronously and using AsyncTask.onPostExecute() handle result, or explicitly using AsyncTask.get() block UI thread and wait for worker thread return result. Note that the latter actually sacrifice the benefit of AsyncTask and may cause ANR exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how I got it working

```
public class Main extends ListActivity {

    String MY_APP_TAG = "com.vidyut";
    ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        myAsyncTask task = new myAsyncTask();
        task.execute();

}

    private class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<Object>, ArrayList<Object>, ArrayList<Object>>
    {
        ProgressDialog dialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Main.this, "", "Loading....");
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Object> doInBackground(ArrayList<Object>... params) {

            String host = "api.twitter.com";
            String twitterURL = "http://"+host+"/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=i1990jain&amp;count;=10";
         try {
          HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
             BasicHttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
             HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost(host, 80, "http");
             HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(twitterURL);
             httpget.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
             HttpResponse response = client.execute(targetHost, httpget, localContext);
             HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
             Object content = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
             Log.d(MY_APP_TAG, "OK: " + content.toString());

             JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(content.toString());

          for(int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++){
           JSONObject jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
           list.add(jo.getString("text"));
          }
         } catch(Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
         }
            return list;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Object> list) {
            dialog.dismiss();

             Log.d(MY_APP_TAG, "The returned list contains " +list.size()+ "elements");
             setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Object>(Main.this, R.layout.tweet, R.id.tweet,list));
                ListView lv = getListView();
                lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                  // When clicked, show a Toaster
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's `AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>`. So you should declare it as `AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Object>>`.

Return the list from the `doInBackground` method.

Comment: returning the list is not possible from doInBackground

Comment: It's not? But that's exactly what you're doing in the answer you posted... Exactly what I said.

Answer (score 1):

To update your activity with a fresh data from an async thread you could use the onProgressUpdate()/onPostExecute() method, or If your are using a Thead you should use an Heandler.

```
//aciticty class:
final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

//inside an async thread
handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //update GUI thread here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Where do you want to return your results? You can access listItems in:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
```

and this is where you should use listItems to for example populate your list. This method is being run on UI thread so it is safe to do it in it.

In your doInBackground I dont see listItems to be initialized to any value, so it is probably null. You should actually create separate instance of listItems to be used in doInBackground, and then assign it to listView inside onPostExecute.